# crash in a Qt app in my reimplementation of QApplication::notify()

Tags: c++, debugging, qt

I have a crash which occur seldom  (one times or two times per day).

I develop under MSVC2010 and in order to understand what's in going on, I debug using the "attach to process" feature provided by MSVC.
Each times the application crash the debugger break inside my reimplementation of QApplication::notify() which is very simple  :

```
bool AutomateQtApplication::notify(QObject *rec, QEvent *ev) 
{ 
        return QApplication::notify(rec, ev);
}
```

the call stack is just about QtGui.dll (not the line of source code juste QtGui.dll) so no help..

Any ideas of what I can do to discover where is the bug or what's going wrong ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does the crash go away if you remove the AutomateQtApplication::notify method from your class?  If it does, that would be a clue.  Also try doing a full/clean rebuild of your app in case there is an out-of-date object file that is subtly messing things up.  If all else fails, you can put a fprintf(stderr, "rec=%p ev=%p", rec, ev); call at the beginning of notify function, and see what arguments got passed to notify just before the crash.  Also if you can compile your app under Linux you could run it under valgrind, which might help you track down the problem.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Those are excellent suggestions. You should put them in an answer.

Comment: Does the crash go away if you remove the AutomateQtApplication::notify method from your class? -> I will try it on monday but i doubt the result will be different.With debugger I can introspect rec and ev, but it's not trivial it is pointer which are not very speaking

Comment: maybe I should use a full debug version of my software in production, to be able to have call stack inside QtGui.dll ?

Comment: @Guillaume07: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar problem, but I'm not re-implementing the `notify()` method.

Comment: @joxl: no sorry, I don't remember the fix